# Stata tab over entire dataset

Tags: search, stata, summary

In Stata is there any way to tabulate over the entire data set as opposed to just over one variable/column?  This would give you the tabulation over all the columns.

Related - is there a way to find particular values in Stata if one does not know which column they occur in?  The output would be which column and row they are located in or at least which column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stata does not use row and column terminology except with reference to matrices and vectors. It uses the terminology of observations and variables.

You could `stack` or `reshape` the entire dataset into one variable if and only if all variables are numeric or all are string. If that assumption is incorrect, then you would need to convert numeric variables to string, at least temporarily, before you could do that. I guess wildly that you are only interested in blocks of variables that are all either numeric or string.

When you say "tabulate" you may mean the `tabulate` command. That has limits on the number of rows and/or columns it can show that might bite, but with a small amount of work `list` could be used for a simple table with many more values.

`tabm` from `tab_chi` on SSC may be what you seek.

For searching across several variables, you could automate a loop.

I'd say that if this is a felt need, it is quite probable that you have the wrong data structure for at least some of what you want to do and should `reshape`. But further details might explode that.

Comment: Makes sense.  Yes, I was referring to the `tabulate` command.  And `stack` I think would work for this assuming I don't have too many observations.